# java NIO file upload, packet loss

Tags: java

Code first

```java
ByteBuffer readBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(requestSize);// here is 1024*1024*1024 = 1G
readBuffer.clear();

SocketChannel socketChannel = (SocketChannel) selectionKey.channel();

while (socketChannel.read(readBuffer)> 0) {}

/* Get request message */
readBuffer.flip();
byte[] bytes = new byte[readBuffer.limit()];
readBuffer.get(bytes);
```

As shown in the code above, the capacity of the buffer ByteBuffer is set to 1G, but uploading a file of about 30M often results in packet loss, resulting in incomplete files, and then an error is reported during formData parsing.

If the capacity of this buffer is much larger than the file, there is no problem at all, but I cannot set the buffer too large, otherwise the heap will overflow.

Please give pointers to those who are familiar with NIO

Comment: Try changing `> 0` to `>= 0`.  Only a negative return value indicates end-of-stream.  See [the `read` method’s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html#read(java.nio.ByteBuffer)).

Comment: Thank you, but if it is changed to >=0, it enters an infinite loop. You can never finish reading. Only if you cancel this request will it become -1

Comment: Doesn’the client stop sending and close the connection when the file has been fully uploaded?

Comment: No, the client needs to wait for a response, because I am developing an http service based on NIO

Comment: 1 GB is much larger than 30 MB. 30 MB is only 3% of 1 GB. How much larger does it need to be? I think the problem is something else.

Comment: Then how is your server supposed to know when the entire file has been sent?  You certainly can’t rely on `read` returning zero, since that can happen as the result of a normal lull in throughput.  If the socket won’t be closed, you should have the client first send four bytes indicating the size of the data that’s about to be sent.  This will also allow you to allocate a more efficient buffer, instead of using up an entire gigabyte of program memory.